# How to sum in EXCEL all the column that have a part of the name in common

Tags: excel, office365

I have different columns with the name that is as in this example:

str1a str1b str2a str2b etc... I would like to sum all the columns that have in common in the name ex:  str1.

[image]

How it is possible?

Thank you

Comment: But you have also `str2` common in two column. Also put few sample data.

Comment: I edited with an example

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT()` may work for you-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:E1,4)="str1")*(A2:E6))
```

[image]

Comment: or, if you want to be a bit more flexible: =SUMPRODUCT(A2:E2;--NOT(ISERROR(FIND("str1";$A$1:$F$1))))

Comment: thank you a lot.....honestly I don't know why people gave to the question a bad reputation considering that I haven't found another similar here and it could be useful also for others. You are very gentle and efficient. Thanks again @Harun24hr also  Marco Vos

Comment: @batardavelo So, did it work? If it helps you then consider tick mark the answer.